# How to extract WebElementObject's attributes?

Tags: webtools

For example one can get `WebElementObject` like so:

```
el = WebExecute[{"OpenPage" -> "mathematica.stackexchange.com", 
   "LocateElements" -> "XPath" -> "/html/body/header[2]/div/a"}][[2,1]]
```

Right now it seems the only way to extract element attributes (e.g. href for `<a>` tag) with `WebExecute` framework, is to write some `JavascriptExecute` query. Is there a more straight forward solution?

Answer (score 7):

As of 12.3 (I haven't checked the earlier versions), there is an undocumented command `ElementAttribute` to extract attributes:

```
session = StartWebSession[]; 
WebExecute["OpenPage" -> "https://wolfram.com"]; 
elements = WebExecute["LocateElements" -> "CSSSelector" -> "div > a.item-0"]; 
WebExecute["ElementAttribute" -> {First@elements, "href"}]
(* "https://blog.wolfram.com/2021/11/30/six-reasons-why-the-wolfram-language-is-like-open-source/?source=frontpage-news" *)
```

How did I discover it, you ask? Well, it's one of the commands that is defined in `/Applications/Wolfram Desktop.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Components/WebUnit/Kernel/wdElement.m`, so I just tried it and it seems to work - probably an omission on Wolfram Research's part to not include it in the documentation.

Answer (score 5):

After some spelunking into `` WebUnit`Private ``, I've found some helpful functions like `get`, `fetch` and `attribute`, that could be used to do exactly what I need:

```
getAttribute[element_WebElementObject, attribute_String] := 
 getAttribute[$CurrentWebSession, element, attribute]

getAttribute[session_WebSessionObject, element_WebElementObject, attribute_String] := 
 With[{sessionInfo = session /@ {"SessionID", "Browser", "URL"}}, 
  WebUnit`Private`attribute[sessionInfo, element["ElementId"], attribute]]
```

Hope it would be included in some form as an official documented functionallity in the future.

Comment: I use this function all the time.  Have you considered submitting it to the Wolfram Function Repository?

Comment: @kickert, see my answer below - the functionality is there, it just looks like a documentation omission. I will submit a bug report to WR.