How to manipulate a dataset using keywords
Given:
data1 = {
   {URL["https://lex.uz/en/docs/3815506"], "On Plant Protection", 
    "PD 34", {"Plant quarantine", "Plant health", 
     "Soil health"}}, {URL["https://lex.uz/en/docs/6906672"], 
    "On Land Reform", 
    "Law 56", {"Land tenure", "Soil health", "Land lease"}}
         };
ds1 = Query[All, {"Links" -> All}]@
   Dataset[AssociationThread[{"Links", "Titles", "Number", 
         "Keywords"} -> #] & /@ data1];
expand1 = 
 ds1[Query[All, 
    row |-> Map[<|"Keywords" -> #, "Number" -> row["Number"], 
        "Titles" -> row["Titles"], "Links" -> row["Links"]|> &, 
      row["Keywords"]]]][Flatten]

I select keywords using:
selectKeywordPartial[dataset_, keyword_] := 
 Select[dataset, StringContainsQ[#Keywords, keyword] &]
selectKeywordPartial[expand1, {"Tenure", "Soil"}]

This selection based on keywords are Case sensitive and I do not want a case sensitive selection. How can I select keywords and associated rows using Case insensitive option?
In web search, I only get titles with hyperlinks. Is there an automatic method to extract the URL links attached to the titles and present them as a dataset with titles and URL links separately, like in the above example?

For case insensitive search the IgnoreCase Option can be used StringContainsQ[#Keywords, keyword, IgnoreCase -> True]

@vindobona: Thanks for the tip. For my second question, I found the link https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/216179/60365 answering my question. Earlier I could not reach this answer.

@vindobona: This link does not really explain what I want to achieve. So my second question still remains to be a question to answer.
