# How to use WebExecute to retrieve WebElementObject HTML?

Tags: webdriver

I know that I can use `WebExecute` to retrieve `WebElementObject` text, as in this example:

```
StartWebSession["Chrome"]
WebExecute["OpenPage"->"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_and_dependencies_by_population"]
table = First@WebExecute["LocateElements"->"XPath"->"//*[@id=\"mw-content-text\"]/div/table"]
WebExecute["ElementText"->table]
```

And that I can retrieve the complete page HTML:

```
html = WebExecute["JavascriptExecute"->"return document.documentElement.outerHTML;"]
```

**The question is:** How can I get `WebElementObject` table data as HTML instead of text?

I explored some `WebUnit` functions, but without success.

**COMPLEMENT**

You can convert your HTML to data using:

```
ImportString[getAttribute[table, "innerHTML"],  {"HTML", "Data"}]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Had to dig a bit, but since it's just using the W3C [WebDriver](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/) stuff you can do it by hand since `WebExecute` doesn't seem to expose all the requests:

```
getWebElementPropertyURL[el_, prop_] :=
  URLBuild@
   ReplacePart[
    URLParse[el["URL"]],
    "Path" -> {"session", el["SessionID"], "element", el["ElementId"], 
      "property",
      prop
      }
    ];
getWebElementProperty[el_, prop_] :=
 Import[getWebElementPropertyURL[el, prop], "RawJSON"]["value"]

getWebElementProperty[table, "innerHTML"]

"#cite_note-218\">[197]</a></sup>
</td></tr>
</tbody><tfoot><tr>
<th></th>
<th style=\"text-align:left\"><span class=\"flagicon\" style=\"padding-left:25px;\">&nbsp;</span>World</th>
<th style=\"text-align:left\">7,771,541,000</th>
<th style=\"text-align:left\">100%</th>
<th style=\"text-align:left\"><span data-sort-value=\"000000002020-03-14-0000\" style=\"white-space:nowrap\">14 Mar 2020</span></th>
<th style=\"text-align:left\">UN projection<sup id=\"cite_ref-219\" class=\"reference\"><a href=\"#cite_note-219\">[198]</a></sup>
</th></tr></tfoot>"
```

You could generalize this stuff to any request you want, as documented [here](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/)

Comment: Cool! [This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/203005/2266) is another option to get element properties using `WebUnit`.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to import the HTML as a Wolfram XML expression and pull out the bits you need and then convert them back to a string again:

```
xml = ImportString[html, {"HTML", "XMLObject"}];
FirstCase[xml, data : XMLElement["table", __] :> ExportString[data, "XML"], Missing[], Infinity]
```