# Incomplete web image scraping

Tags: import, image

Occasionally when I scrape images from a webpage, such as:

```
Import["https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/mondrian.html", "Images"]
```

only a portion of the images are returned (v. 11.3.0.0, MacOS).  Is *Mathematica* imposing some total file size constraint?

One workaround is to download just the internal Hyperlinks on the webpage

```
Import["https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/mondrian.html", 
"Hyperlinks"]
```

and then edit (by hand) to pick out the links to relevant images and download those individually, but this seems inelegant.

How can I ensure I scrape *all* images on a webpage?

Comment: If you open the "network" tab in your browser (f12 on chrome), then you can see that a lot of the content is not loaded immediately when you go to the page, but rather when you start scrolling down. If you want to get all pages, you would need to imitate scrolling down the page. Potentially with JavaScript, or accessing their API in another way.

Comment: @enano9314:  Thanks.  I don't program in *JavaScript*.  Is there some simple modification to the *Mathematica* `Import` code to "scroll down"?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork nope, you need to use `WebExecute` to do stuff like that

Answer (score 4):

**Update** Add the image URL's

```
{https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/mondrian8p.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian1.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian2.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian3.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian4.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian5.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian6.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian7.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian8.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian9.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian12.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian11.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian13.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian17.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian10.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian14.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian15.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian16.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian18.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian74.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian21.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian19.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian20.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian22.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian23.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian24.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian25.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian27.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian32.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian33.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian26.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian28.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian29.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian30.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian31.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian34.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian35.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian36.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian37.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian38.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian39.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian41.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian42.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian43.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian40.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian46.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian44.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian45.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian47.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian48.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian49.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian50.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian51.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian52.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian53.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian76.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian77.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian55.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian75.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian54.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian56.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian65.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian57.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian58.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian59.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian63.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian64.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian62.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian61.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian66.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian67.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian68.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian69.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian70.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian71.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian72.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian60.jpg,https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/smondrian73.jpg}
```

---

Using the helper function `getWebElementProperty` written by @b3m2a1 [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/216250/58370).

```
session = StartWebSession[]
WebExecute[session, "OpenPage" -> "https://www.freeart.com/gallery/m/mondrian/mondrian.html"]

imageTags = WebExecute[session, "LocateElements" -> "Tag" -> "img"];
imageURLs = getWebElementProperty[#, "src"] & /@ imageTags //
  Select[StringContainsQ[#, "https://www.freeart.com/gallery"] &]
```

gets all of the image URLs which can be used to `Import`.

Then delete the session

```
DeleteObject[session]
```

Comment: RohitNamjoshi:  Thanks so much.  This looks like it may work, but alas I have only v. 11.3.0.0 and `StartWebSession` was introduced in v. 12.  Is there any workaround that will implement your code in v. 11?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork There is support for this in v11 using `StartExternalSession` which is documented [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/externalevaluationsystem/WebDriverChrome.html). I have no experience using it. There are several related [posts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=webdriver-chrome) on MSE that might help.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I added the image URLs in case you needed them.

Comment: Thanks... but alas I just can't seem to get everything to work.  I upvoted your answer, and will accept it once I somehow figure everything out.  You've helped a lot, but a solution that includes everything from start to finish that gives me all images on a large webpage would be accepted.